# How to send message email?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to message an email very user which is admin. But this code shows me the error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::all()`. So how can I send every admin email message?

Comment: You need to use `->get()` since you've built a query. See https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#building-queries

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public function index()
{
    // notify a single user
    $user = User::where('role', 'Admin')->first();

    $project = [
        'greeting' => 'Hi '.$user->login.',',
        'body'       => 'This is the project assigned to you.',
        'thanks'     => 'Thank you this is from codeanddeploy.com',
        'id'         => 1
    ];

    $user->notify(new EmailNotification($project));
    return view('customers', [
        'customers' => Customer::all()
    ]);
}
```

To notify multiple users try

```
$users = User::where('role', 'Admin')->get();

foreach($users as $user) {
   $user->notify(new EmailNotification($project));
}
```

Comment: You need to make sure that User Model has the Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable trait to use the notify feature. then configure your email service under mail.php config file